# Javascript synchronous writing to a file and reading from a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization

I have a need to store data in variable, store whole variable to a file and then read it from a file.

How to achieve that with Java script?

Tried with:

```
fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/data.txt', JSON.stringify(objectData));
fs.readFile('/tmp/data.txt', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

But second part is executing before file write finishes giving either corrupted data or partial one.

How to achieve above scenario?

Comment: [The `data` parameter will be a Buffer instance, not a string.](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case it's better if you use fs.writeFile as described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback), to ensure if your write has been done and then read your file:

```
fs.writeFile('/tmp/data.txt', JSON.stringify(objectData), (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
fs.readFile('/tmp/data.txt', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
});
```